# Specify Location of Certificate Signing Requests in OpenSSL Configuration File?

Tags: openssl

Does the OpenSSL `req` command have a OpenSSL configuration file equivalent to the `ca` command's `new_certs_dir` option?  I'd like to establish a default directory for all Certificate Signing Requests ("CSRs") that are created using the `req` command.

Comment: This question makes no sense for me. As documented `openssl req` either outputs to the given file name or to stdout. If one does not provide an absolute file name it is relativ to the current working directory where `openssl req` is executed - similar to how other programs handle file names.

Comment: I don't want to have to remember to specify the location where the CSR file will be saved as part of the '-out' option or have to navigate to the directory where my CSRs are stored when using the 'req' option to create a new CSR.  If I understand the 'ca' command's 'new_certs_dir' option correctly, it passes the path of the directory where all new certs created by the 'ca' command are saved.  I want to know if that same functionality is available for the 'req' command.

Comment: This functionality is not there. And contrary to `ca` the `req` command creates exactly the files you gave on the command line so such functionality is not needed. I also don't understand why you cannot remember the directory but you can remember the name of the file.  Anyway, just use an absolute path for these files or create a wrapper script around it where you hard code the path you want.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks, Steffen for the quick answer.  The wrapper is a great idea.  If you submit this as an answer I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such functionality is not there - and it is not needed: contrary to `ca` the `req` command creates exactly the files as given on the command line. So the easiest way is to use absolute path with `req` and creating a wrapper script around it which sets the directory part for these absolute path based on your preference.